# staying in debugger mode after error

Tags: r, rstudio

When in debugger mode (in RStudio) the debugger stops when an error (in debugging mode) occurs. Is it possible to stay in the debugger, so that code can be developped directly in the debugger?

Imagine the following situation:

```
foo <- function(a){
  print("before")
  browser()

  # Error
  "a" + 1

  print(a)
}

foo(2)
```

When executing the code above, debugger mode is started when `browser()` is reached (I know there are breakpoints in RStudio, but lets do it with browser() for now). When executing the next line (which contains an error) the debugger will be closed (an the parameter `a` will be lost). I then have to clean the code an debug again.

In some situations it would be much easier if I could develep the code in the debugger without leaving and restarting it. This might be "bad practice" but very useful in some situations. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you already search for an answer / asked [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us)?

Comment: no, couldn't find your question. Can you give me the keywords to find it? Thx

Comment: sorry, misread the "slash" / as an I :-)